# GWT handle events of UIBinder

Tags: javascript, gwt

i built an UIBinder that has selectBox and table. the table is filled with data from db. 
when i change the selection of the selectBox i should go and run a query to get the new data. 
i use the Widget in a screen view, and start it at the presenter. 
at the UIBinder i fired event when my selectBox is changed, but i can't catch it on the presenter. 
how i can do that successfully. 
my event at the widget:

```
@Override
public void onChange(ChangeEvent event)
{
    KPIOptionChangedEvent e = new KPIOptionChangedEvent();
    fireEvent(e);
}
```

catching the event at the presenter:

```
eventBus.addHandler(KPIEvents.KPIOptionChangedEvent.TYPE,
    new KPIHandlers.KPIOptionChangedHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void execute(KPIOptionChangedEvent event)
        {
            Window.alert(event.getKPI().getName());
        }
    });
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`fireEvent(e)` is defined on `Widget` and is used to fire events on a widget instance.

If you want to send an event through EventBus then call:

```
eventBus.fire(e);
```

Comment: that what i do now and it's not working: 
KPIOptionChangedEvent e = new KPIOptionChangedEvent();
   
   HandlerManager eventBus = new HandlerManager(this); 
   eventBus.fireEvent(e);
           
    
  }

Comment: You should create only one EventBus per application - there is no need to create multiple EventBuses, as they do not communicate between themselves and it just creates confusion. 
Use a static field in one of your main classes.

Comment: i understand, but my object shouldn't be connected to things from the main or other logic classes. it should act dependantly.

Comment: You can organize your code however you want, just make sure you have only one instance of HandlerManager per application. This is called singleton. You can do this via a static field or a singleton factory method. If you are really concerned about independency of classes the take a look at GIN: http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/

Comment: Btw, `HandlerManager` is being deprecated. Google suggests to use EventBus instead (specifically one of its subclasses, primarily `SimpleEventBus`).

Comment: Thanks for your tips and help. 
but i think that my object can't be related to my program, textbox for example throw events with out any relation to the program that is using it. that is the way i want my object to act. 
is there anyway to do that?

Comment: This are two different things. Textbox fires event with the help of browser's DOM, so it has dependency on DOM. Your object, if it wants to fire events must depend on EventBus, or something else than knows how to transmit events between sources and targets. Now, if you do not want to hardcode this dependencies, then google "dependency injection". For GWT there is GIN.